# How to Read Files with XMLHttpRequest in JS

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

How would I do that? My file is called `ajax_info.txt` and my response should be a self-called [handler] function.

Comment: What do you mean by _"my response should be a self-called function"_? Surely your response should be the contents of the file.

Comment: No, I mean a self-called handler function.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with the following code:

```js
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
xhttp.send();
(function(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
})()
```

Where the file to read is `ajax_info.txt`, and the response function is the last three lines.